# Need a thread-safe asynchronous message queue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, message-queue

I'm looking for a Python class (preferably part of the standard language, rather than a 3rd party library) to manage asynchronous 'broadcast style' messaging.

I will have one thread which puts messages on the queue (the 'putMessageOnQueue' method must not block) and then multiple other threads which will all be waiting for messages, having presumably called some blocking 'waitForMessage' function. When a message is placed on the queue I want each of the waiting threads to get its own copy of the message.

I've looked at the built-in `Queue` class, but I don't think this is suitable because consuming messages seems to involve removing them from the queue, so only 1 client thread would see each one.

This seems like it should be a common use-case, can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: I believe you can build your own class that keeps tracks of which thread got which message, without many problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the typical approach to this is to use a separate message queue for each thread, and push the message onto every queue which has previously registered an interest in receiving such messages.

Something like this ought to work, but it's untested code...

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

class DispatcherThread(Thread):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(DispatcherThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.interested_threads = []

   def run(self):
       while 1:
           if some_condition:
               self.dispatch_message(some_message)
           else:
               sleep(0.1)

   def register_interest(self, thread):
       self.interested_threads.append(thread)

   def dispatch_message(self, message):
       for thread in self.interested_threads:
           thread.put_message(message)



class WorkerThread(Thread):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.queue = Queue()


   def run(self):

       # Tell the dispatcher thread we want messages
       dispatcher_thread.register_interest(self)

       while 1:
           # Wait for next message
           message = self.queue.get()

           # Process message
           # ...

   def put_message(self, message):
       self.queue.put(message)


dispatcher_thread = DispatcherThread()
dispatcher_thread.start()

worker_threads = []
for i in range(10):
    worker_thread = WorkerThread()
    worker_thread.start()
    worker_threads.append(worker_thread)

dispatcher_thread.join()
```

Comment: Perfect, that works great! Shame there isn't a ready-made version, but I guess the principle isn't that complicated once someone explains it clearly (as you did).

Comment: @codebox Well, there's better support in the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module, but that's for subprocesses rather than threads. I guess that's because inter-process communication is usually more complex than inter-thread communication, since threads naturally share the same heap.

Comment: If you need a **broadcast** from one writer, is the queue best solution? Perhaps it would be better to use a **write-once/read-many** structure, which every process could read concurrently, on their own free time?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a more straight forward example (taken from the Queue example in [Python Lib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) )

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue


num_worker_threads = 2

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: How does that meet the question's requirements? He explicitly said Queue doesn't work because every thread needs a copy of the item.