# Save to database inside thread

Tags: python, django, multithreading, sqlite, queue

I'm working with django,

I have a thread whose purpose is to take queued list of database items and modify them

Here is my model :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    boolean = models.BooleanField(editable=False)
```

and the problematic code :

```
def unqueue():
    while not queue.empty():
        myList = queue.get()
        for i in myList:
            if not i.boolean:
                break
            i.boolean = False
            i.save()   # <== error because database table is locked
        queue.task_done()


queue = Queue()

thread = Thread(target=unqueue)
thread.start()

def addToQueue(pk_list): # can be called multiple times simultaneously
    list = []
    for pk in pk_list:
        list.append(MyModel.objects.get(pk=pk))
    queue.put(list)
```

I now the code is missing lot of check ect... I simplified here to make it clearer

What can I do to be able to save to my db while inside the thread ?

EDIT : I need to be synchronous because i.boolean (and other properties in my real code) mustn't be overwrite

I tried to create a dedicated Table in the database but it didn't work, I still have the same issue

EDIT 2 : I should precise that I'm using SQLite3. I tried to see if I could unlock/lock specific table in SQLite and it seem that locking apply on the entire db only. That is probably why using a dedicated table wasn't helpful.

That is bad for me, because I need to access different table simultaneously from different thread, is it possible ?

EDIT 3 : It seems that my problem is the one listed here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/#database-is-locked-errors

Comment: I'm curious what made you choose this approach over, say, letting the client(s) handle POSTing data asynchronously?

Comment: In fact, I need to be sure myObject is written only once, it is not visible here, but I have to check whether my boolean is alread false or not before modifying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to change database,

SQLite don't allow concurency access like that.

I switched to MySql and it work now

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a synchronized queue? May be asynchronous solution will solve your problem? [Need a thread-safe asynchronous message queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857883/need-a-thread-safe-asynchronous-message-queue)

Comment: Yes, I am absolutly sure, I need to be sure that myitem is not written multiple time, It needs to be written only once